# CSS dual background issues

Tags: html, css

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <title>Main Website</title>
 <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>



    <body>
    <nav>
    <div>  
        <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="mens_clothing.html">Mens Clothing</a></li>
              <li><a href="women_clothing.html">Womens Clothng</a></li>
              <li><a href="boys_clothing.html">Boys Clothing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>


<div class="container">

    <div>


        <div>

            <div class="accordion">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="caption"><a href="#">Slide 1</a></div>
                            <a href="#">
                        <img src='Slider_Image1.jpg'/></a>
                        </li>

                    <li>
                            <div class="caption"><a href="#">Slide 2</a></div>
                            <a href="#">
                        <img src='Slider_Image2.jpg'/></a>
                        </li>

                    <li>
                            <div class="caption"><a href="#">Slide 3</a></div>
                            <a href="#">
                        <img src='Slider_Image3.jpg'/></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div>

                 <div class="centre , fade ,">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                     <a href="Nike_Shoes1.html">
                        <img src="Image1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="centre , fade">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="Nike_Trainers.html">
                        <img src="Image2.jpg" alt="">

                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="centre , fade">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="Image3.jpg" alt="">   
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div  class="centre , fade">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="new.html">
                        <img src="Mens_Clothing.jpg" alt="Mens Clothing">  
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div  class="centre , fade">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="women_clothing.html">
                        <img src="Womens_Clothing.jpg" alt="Womens Clothing">
                    </div>
                </div>


                 <div  class="centre , fade">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="boys_clothing.html">
                        <img src="Boys_Clothing.jpg" alt="Boys Clothing">
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div  class="centre , fade">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="Converse_clothing.jpg" alt="Converse Clothing">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div  class="centre , fade">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="Adidas_clothing.jpg" alt="Adidas Clothing">
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>



    </footer>

</div>
```

Here is the code for a website I am developing and I am trying to add images for the background. What I am looking to do is add 2 images on either side of the webpage, I am not sure on how to go about this also while trying to add an image as my background I see a white area the image is not set as the background, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to merge the two images into one image using an image editor and then setting the merged image as your background.

Answer (score 0):

Just open paint glue the 2 images together and use it as background.